# Youtube video in landscape mode within a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

My application was not made ​​for the landscape. But when I open my YouTube channel in a **UIWebView** and a user **launches a video**, it appears in Portrait. I would like to make it appear in landscape mode if the user rotate his iPhone.

How to **enable landscape** mode as in this case?

*I know there are "dirty hacks" to do this but I prefer something cleaner. Also I do not want the UIWebView switches to landscape but just that the videos can.*

Comment: ps. 'Normal' mode is 'Portrait'

Comment: @DanielHanly Yes ^^ English is not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally adjusted my view so that it supports landscape mode using the following code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation))
    {
        //I set my new frame origin and size here for this orientation
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        //I set my new frame origin and size here for this orientation
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // We must add a delay here, otherwise we'll swap in the new view
    // too quickly and we'll get an animation glitch
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateLandscapeView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)updateLandscapeView
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        //I set my new frame origin and size here for this orientation
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait && isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        //I set my new frame origin and size here for this orientation
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }    
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
}
```

Comment: nice job! but is that you need to adjust entire your UI in landscape orientation?? What should i do if i only want to play the video in landscape mode, and the rest of the UI should be stay the same in the portrait mode?

Comment: isShowingLandscapeView is it the UIWebview or other else view?

Comment: likewise, i have been able to make my View Controller landscape, but the video still launches in portrait :/

Answer (score 0):

To show your video in landscape view, just go to the attribute inspector of that view where you have implemented your webView in Xcode
and change the orientation from portrait to landscape.
as simple as that..enjoy

and dont forget to add this code

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { 
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {   
            return YES;  
    } 
}
```

Comment: No I just want to stay in portrait mode for the view. But now if I stay in portrait mode and I run a video I can not make the rotation on the player only. That's what I want to do, to see the videos in landscape mode but keep the view in portrait mode. I just wanted to know if it was possible.

Comment: @Anas10 for that thing dont go for the code i.e shouldAutorotate... just change the property of the View to landscape(As mentioned in my above answer) then when you will see the video the view will be loaded in the landscape mode only.

Comment: It did not work, I finally adjusted my view so that it supports landscape mode.

Comment: note that "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" becomes "shouldAutorotate" in iOS 6+

Comment: this doesn't work in my case - i have a View Controller that is set to landscape only, and the video is STILL only launching in Portrait mode... thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

id presentedViewController = [window.rootViewController presentedViewController];
NSString *className = presentedViewController ? NSStringFromClass([presentedViewController class]) : nil;
if (window && [className isEqualToString:@"AVFullScreenViewController"] && [presentedViewController isBeingDismissed] == NO) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
} else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}}
```

//This Works for ios8