# How to make an html embeded video in webview play in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

Hi i ve got a youtube url where i m loading it in html embeded webview. everything is working fine.the video plays in potrait mode.the problem is when i rotate the device to landscape while the video plays in potrait,the video is not getting played in landscape mode.since i m embedding the video in html webview .could u guys help me out in this.

```
   - (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame {
        NSString* embedHTML = @"\
        <html><head>\
        <style type=\"text/css\">\
        body {\
            background-color: transparent;\
        color: white;\
        }\
        </style>\
        </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
        <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
        width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
        </body></html>";
        NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
        if(webView == nil) {
            webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        }
        [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self embedYouTube:urlString frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    }


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation))
    {
        //I set my new frame origin and size here for this orientation
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        //I set my new frame origin and size here for this orientation
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}

- (void)updateLandscapeView
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        //I set my new frame origin and size here for this orientation
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait && isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        //I set my new frame origin and size here for this orientation
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // We must add a delay here, otherwise we'll swap in the new view
    // too quickly and we'll get an animation glitch
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateLandscapeView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}




- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
}

-(IBAction)onHome{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: check this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111207/youtube-video-in-landscape-mode-within-a-uiwebview)

Comment: @Mudit:i added the above solution..was not successful..the video gets played in landscape mode only when i rotate my device to landscape orientation and tap the webview..if i m play a video in potrait and then rotate to landscape while the video playes.its not getting set to landscape orientation